# Choreography Sagas in DDD - Chain of Integration Events?

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, saga

I'm currently studying Saga pattern. Most examples seem to focus on Orchestration Sagas where we have one central saga execution coordinator service that dispatches and receives messages/events.  Unfortunately information on how to implement Choreography Sagas seem to be lacking a bit.

In domain driven design, we have multiple bounded contexts, ideally, where each bounded context is a self contained microservice. If microservice A wants to communicate with another microservice B we use Integration Events. Integration Events are published and subscribed to using some asynchronous communication - RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus.

Assuming we want to start some Saga, for example, where we have to run transactions on Order Service and Customer Service - how exactly do services communicate with each other? Is it just regular Integration Events or something entirely different?

The way I see it and given picture below ([source](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)), Saga would be executed this way:

1. A new order is created. Status is set to "Pending" and OrderSubmittedDomainEvent domain event is emitted.
2. Domain event handler receives OrderSubmittedDomainEvent domain event, it then creates and dispatches ReserveCreditIntegrationEvent integration event.
3. Customer Service receives ReserveCreditIntegrationEvent integration event.
4. It attempts to reserve customer credit.
5. If credit is successfully reserved, CustomerCreditReservedDomainEvent domain event is emitted.
6. Domain event handler received CustomerCreditReservedDomainEvent domain event, it creates and dispatches CreditReservedIntegrationEvent integration event.
7. Order Service receives CreditReservedIntegrationEvent integration event and sets Order Status to "Confirmed".
8. saga is completed.

Is this the right approach?

[image: Saga]

Comment: I found this talk helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPbGW3Fnmbc. I don't remember all details about it, but it seems that the given example was a choreography saga

Comment: "If microservice A wants to communicate with another microservice B we use Integration Events." This isn't true. Bounded context is a logical boundary and does not describe a physical/hardware boundary. Bounded context can span across multiple services. If Saga is coordinating worfklow within the Sales Bounded Context, then you use Domain events. If Saga is coordinating workflow across contexts, then you use integration events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using ***Choreography*** rather then ***Orchestration*** for distributed transactions makes sense if you chose it for the right reasons. For instance, if you need to spare the usually higher effort of implementing a central choreography as you ***don't need to know what state a transaction is in*** until it has finished. Or because you know that the order of the transaction workflow is stable and is unlikely to change which would also be on the plus side of choreography. But would be a drawback for Choreography if the order changes frequently because you would need to adapt ***all microservices*** in that case...

So you need to know the advantages and drawbacks of the two approaches.

If you chose Choreography for the right reasons I would say that I am missing the ***compensation logic*** in your considerations. What if the credit was reserved but then the order fails in the order service? Compensation events need to be considered as well in such cases...

Other than that there is the usual suspects:

- such as making sure that each service will reliably send the next event after it processed the received event. For this you could look into the ***[Transactional Outbox](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html)*** pattern.
- or making sure that you have deduplication of events implemented in each of the services as for reliable sending of events accross distributed transactions you cannot be a hundred percent sure that an event will only be sent once.

And if you are even interested in an alternative to the Saga pattern you can look into the ***[Routing Slip](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RoutingTable.html)*** pattern. It is well suited for distributed transaction workflows that will differ depending on the current use case by avoiding that each service needs to know each route. The sequence of the workflow is attached to the initial message of the transaction and all subsequent messages. Then each service receiving a message with the routing slip performs its tasks and passes the next message including the routing slip to the next station (service) on the list.

Note: I am not sure what exactly you mean by *...IntegrationEvent*. I would not differentiate between *domain* and *integration* events, all events are relevant from the business perspective in your example otherwise they would not be relevant to other Microservices.

Comment: Integration events are vital for DDD (Domain Driven Design) and are differentiated by their scope. Domain events only apply within a single bounded context (i.e. Sales) whereas integration events are communication between bounded contexts (i.e. Sales talks to Support). In most mature architectures that follow DDD domain events should be differentiated from integration events. Successful application of the bounded contexts prevents creating big balls of mud.